# PHPExcel generate htm instead of xls

Tags: phpexcel, xls

I need to generate xls files using PHPExcel class, but I have problem with extention:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="File.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
...
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Using this code browser wants to download File.xls.htm file insetead of File.xls ... Why ?
Version of PHPExcel what I have used 1.7.8, 2012-10-12

Comment: What type of is a File.xls.html? If you want a straight HTML markup download, then you use the HTML writer, and don't set headers to xls mimetype

Comment: I faced with the same issue. Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any white spaces or "empty" echo's in your *.php